# Problems after updating 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ati

During software update it went to a bank screen and I rebooted it. After that the system wouldn't boot. Grub showed and I chose ubuntu but it just went to a black screen. I removed the AMD proprietary drivers trough a bootable pendrive and now I can get to the login screen. But after login in unity doesnt open and it takes a long time for it to recognize my mouse and keyboard. I cant open almost anything by terminal because it says libGL.so.1 is missing.

Is there a solution or is my installation completely messed up? Im starting to think it would be easier to do a clean install...

Comment: can you connect to internet in grub?

Comment: If you mean enabling networking on recoverymode, yes I can

Comment: close this topic. I was able to reinstall everything xorg and libgl trough synaptic and get unity to start but i was still getting random compiz and unity errors. I guess other packages got broken from the upgrade. I ended up doing  clean install...